# How to solve after upload the image missing in html

Tags: laravel

I am doing an image upload. The image successfully uploads but when press the button the image will missing.
This is my interface for image upload

[image]

when I select the image
the default image will change to the image I select

[image]

ut after I press the upload button to the backend it works but the selected image will become back the default one.  Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks in advance

Here is my code:

```
<form method="POST" action="url" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload">
     @csrf 
     <div class="d-flex mb-2 ms-1 justify-content-md-center">
     <img src="{{ asset('assets/images/placeholder.png') }}"/>  
     </div>
     <label class="btn me-75 mb-0" for="picture">
       <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Upload</span>
       <input class="form-control" type="file" name="image" id="change" accept="image/*" hidden required/>   
     </label>
    </form>
```

Comment: If your page is refreshed when you upload the image, you need to return the saved image URL from the controller, and if you have any image link on the page load, you can assign it into img src.

Comment: @Bulent I see, I will try it. Thanks for your reply